# Javascript discontinuous stacked bar graph

Tags: javascript, plot, graph, charts, time-management

I am trying to plot daily tasks in what i would describe as a discontinuous stacked bar graph. Another description would be a vertical gantt chart of past events.

If the description is lacking, the result i want is something like that shown in the image below (made in paint).

[image: Desired result]

All task have a duration (from-to time) and can have different categories which results in different colours with belonging legends.

I have been playing around with two javascript plotting libraries; chart.js and plotly.js, and looking at others but i haven't found anything that can do what i want to achieve. Both chart.js and plotly have stacked bar graphs, but i see no way of getting spaces in between the bars and getting the legends right.

Do anyone have an idea if this is possible in any these two libraries? If not is there an alternative library where this can be done?

Regards

Comment: you could add a space by adding a bar with a transparent color

Comment: Yeah, considered that, but the colours and the legends become tricky.